# How to access to the package contents of Julia in Mac? It's easy to find the package content in Windows but I can't find them in Mac

Tags: julia

I am using Mac and I downloaded a Julia package and I like to edit a function inside it, where I can access to the functions inside the package. I know how to do it in Windows but I can't find it in Mac.

I already looked into Julia contents but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Package installations are (supposed to be) immutable, and in fact the files are set to read-only mode, so you are not supposed to modify what is in the `$HOME/.julia/packages/` folders.

If you want to make changes you should obtain the full git clone of the package. You can use the convenience function [`Pkg.develop`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/api/#Pkg.develop) for this purpose (or the `develop` Pkg REPL command). `Pkg.develop` downloads a full git clone of the package, and (by default) puts in in the `$HOME/.julia/dev/` folder, where you can make your changes.

The location should be the same on macOS as on Windows (except that `$HOME` probably expands to different paths).